# func drop(while) of Array in swift does not work properly

Tags: swift

In Xcode 11.3 or 12.2
Sample code:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let dropSlices = numbers.drop {
    $0 > 3
}
print(dropSlices)
```

Found dropSlices is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

dropSlices should skip all items that great than 3, should be `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2905036-drop

Comment: You're looking for `prefix(while: { $0 <= 3 })` or `filter { $0 <= 3 }`.

Answer (score 6):

No. `drop(while: predicate)` will drop the collection elements while the condition is met and the first element does not succeed. Therefore no element will be dropped after failing the condition. If you would like to iterate the whole collection you should use `filter` instead or the mutating method `removeAll(where: predicate)`.